# How to check traffic capacity of website on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, vue.js, digital-ocean

I have a web app I built with vue.js and node.js, I am hosting on digital ocean and everything is working fine. I would like to know how many visitors my site can handle simultaneously without crashing. Please I have no idea how to get this so I am open to all ideas.

Comment: you can always do some load testing with tools like k6, jmeter, etc...

Comment: You can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-load-testing), it is from digital ocean.